# How do I copy standard output to a file?

Tags: windows-xp

How do I copy the standard output of a command to a file? I.e. direct it to the file in addition to (not instead of) the console?

Comment: A little dirty solution could be this: command & command > file

Comment: Or without running the command twice: command > file & type file

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: unless the command you're trying to run is `time` or something else where the output may change between runs :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo You're right. That's the reason I post as a comment. I knew  that it was not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get yourself a copy of [`tee`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) from [`GnuWin32`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) (it's part of `CoreUtils`) and use:

```
mycommand | tee myfile
```

If you have (and don't mind using) `powershell`, that command will also work within it, obviating the need for third-party tools.

Comment: Thank you! Just check and the server has the tee already installed!!! Works really nice!